# if(false) vs. while(false): unreachable code vs. dead code

Tags: java, dead-code, unreachable-code

I tried the following in Eclipse:

- `if (false) {}`: warning 'dead code'
- `while (false) {}`: compilation error 'unreachable code'

I was wondering whether there is a real 'reason' for this difference. I already found this...

[Unreachable code compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276378/unreachable-code-compiler-error)

...but why not allow `while (false)` for the same debugging purpose?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The [JLS section on unreachable code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) explains the rationale. Essentially, Java normally shouldn't use conditional compilation like C routinely does with `#ifdef`, but there are some situations (such as debugging, and in particular backward binary compatibility) where allowing the compiler to entirely strip out code is needed, and so the specific construct `if(false)` is permitted for that purpose.

Comment: +1 `but why not allow while (false) for the same debugging purpose?` I didn't get that part?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I'm not always in the mood for JLS archaeology... *most interesting man meme*

Comment: Does that mean that `if(false) {}` is the only exception where the compiler 'allows' unreachable code?

Comment: @NarendraPathai `while(false)` doesn't really make sense for debugging; in a debugging (or binary-compatibility) situation, you'll be either turning off sections or alternating between version (such as the Android compatibility libraries do). In both of these cases, any loops would remain in place, and it's best to keep the exception to the reachability rule as narrow as possible.

Comment: @luukburger Not `if(false)` literally, but `if(compile-time-false-expression)`.

Comment: @NarendraPathai The why is explained at the end of the linked paragraph in the JLS: conditional compilation

Comment: Thanks! On a side note, `while(true)` is another unreachable code scenario, for the code that follows the loop. :-)

Answer (score 9):

You must read the [Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21). Although with `while(false)` the compiler will throw an error but with `if(false)` it wil show a warning to the user.

Although `if (false)` was kept in Java to simulate C/C++ preprocessor `#if 0`

The specification says that:

> if (false) { x=3; }
>
> does not result in a compile-time error. An optimizing compiler may
>   realize that the statement x=3; will never be executed and may choose
>   to omit the code for that statement from the generated class file, but
>   the statement x=3; is not regarded as "unreachable" in the technical
>   sense specified here.
>
> **The rationale for this differing treatment is to allow programmers to
>   define "flag variables"** such as:
>
> static final boolean DEBUG = false; and then write code such as:
>
> if (DEBUG) { x=3; } The idea is that it should be possible to change
>   the value of DEBUG from false to true or from true to false and then
>   compile the code correctly with no other changes to the program text.

Comment: The compiler won't throw an error for `if (false {}`. That's the point.

Comment: I still have the downvote because the compiler will *not* raise an error in the case of `if(false)`.

Comment: @RahulTripathi `while(false)` is a compile-time error. `if(false)` *may* produce a warning but is explicitly *not* a compile-time error.

Comment: @luukburger:- Yes you are correct. I got it wrong. I have updated my answer and the rationale why the compiler will not throw an error!

Comment: It's worth noting that `if (compileTimeConstant) {...}` makes sense as a construct, and `while(true) {...}` and `do {...} while(compileTimeConstant)` make sense, but `while(compileTimeConstant) {...}` doesn't make sense in any case [other than the literal-`true` one] that couldn't be better written as `if (compileTimeConstant) { while(true) {} }`.

Answer (score 0):

However, the 'do-while loop' will compile and execute.

```
do {
    System.out.println("its work!");
} while (false);                       //compile and execute
```