# Why Java identifies unreachable code only in case of while loop?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, unreachable-code

If I have code like

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 0;
    while (false) { x=3; }  //will not compile  
}
```

compiler will complaint that `x=3` is unreachable code but if I have code like

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 0;
    if (false) { x=3; }
    for( int i = 0; i< 0; i++) x = 3;   
}
```

then it compiles correctly though the code inside `if statement` and `for loop` is unreachable. Why is this redundancy not detected by java workflow logic ? Any usecase?

Comment: Weird enough, the `if (false) { x=3; }` part looks as if it was copied right out of [*JSL*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) (scroll all the way to the bottom).

Comment: Naah. I encountered this question in OCJP certification demo exam. Thanks for the JSL link though.

Comment: Well, I guess that one of the guys that were writing the demo was lazy... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), this feature is reserved for "conditional compilation".

An example, described in the JLS, is that you may have a constant

```
static final boolean DEBUG = false;
```

and the code that uses this constant

```
if (DEBUG) { x=3; }
```

The idea is to provide a possibility to change `DEBUG` from `true` to `false` easily without making any other changes to the code, which would not be possible if the above code gave a compilation error.

Comment: +1 for the JLS reference.

Answer (score 2):

The use case with the if condition is debugging. AFAIK it is explicitly allowed by the spec for `if`-statements (not for loops) to allow code like this:

```
class A {
    final boolean debug = false;

    void foo() {
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("bar!");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You can later (or via debugger at runtime) change the value of `debug` to get output.

EDIT
As Christian pointed out in his comment, an answer linking to the spec can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299914/iffalse-vs-whilefalse-unreachable-code-vs-dead-code).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the for loop, I thinks it's just that it's not as easy to detect as the use of a `false` constant inside a while loop.

Regarding the `if`, that was a deliberate choice to authorize it in order to be able to remove debugging code from the byte code at compilation time:

```
private static final boolean DEBUG = false; // or true

...

if (DEBUG) {
    ...
}
```