# Why does compiler recognize while(true) at compile time but not if(true)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, if-statement, while-loop

The below code gives compile time error - Unreachable statement

```
while(true)
  return;
return;  // Unreachable statement
```

But, the following code does not give any error:

```
if(true)
   return;
return;  // Reachable, No Error
```

I am unable to understand why the compiler recognizes that in case of while, the 2nd return statement will never be reached, but it does not recognize the same in case of if?

Comment: Answer: Java sucks at solving the Halting Problem. :)

Comment: Here is specification, if someone is willing to dig into it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21 . At the end it gives rationale, why it considers `x=3;` reachable in `if(false) x=3;`

Comment: Yeah, the bottom line is that the compiler analysis is limited. There's a specific clause regarding `while (true)` statements, the same does not exist for `if`.

Comment: The better dupe is the link pointed at in this question's dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299914/iffalse-vs-whilefalse-unreachable-code-vs-dead-code