# Why does a Java Compiler not produce an unreachable statement error for an unreachable then statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, unreachable-code, unreachable-statement

If I try to compile

```
for(;;)
{

}
System.out.println("End");
```

The Java compiler produces an error saying `Unreachable statement`. But if I add another "*unreachable*"(according to me) `break` statement and make it:

```
for(;;)
{
    if(false) break;
}
System.out.println("End");
```

It compiles. Why does it not produce an error?

Comment: I don't understand your edit: it is an infinite loop regardless of the condition used in the if...

Comment: @assylias I don't think simply addressing the if is a sufficient answer here, or it'd be a duplicate. The trick is that the if backdoor makes the compiler consider the break reachable, which unrolls to provide an exit condition.

Comment: @chrylis yes I understand that - what I meant in my comment is that `continue` is not going to exit anything...

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I specifically do not think this is a duplicate because this question involves an interaction that, while dependent on the special case, requires further analysis.

Comment: @assylias I added that because the JLS description says `A break, continue, return, or throw statement cannot complete normally.`. Even with **return** it produces an error.

Comment: @assylias Right, and the compiler is realizing that even if `continue` is reachable, there's no exit path from the loop.

Comment: The code is unreachable, but it's not Java-unreachable.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The behaviour is defined in [the JLS description of unreachable statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21):

> The then-statement is reachable iff the if-then statement is reachable.

So the compiler determines that the then-statement (`break;`) is reachable, regardless of the condition in the `if`.

And a bit further, emphasis mine:

> A basic `for` statement can complete normally iff at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The for statement is reachable, there is a condition expression, and the condition expression is not a constant expression (§15.28) with value true.
> - ***There is a reachable `break` statement that exits the for statement.***

So the for can complete normally because the then-statement contains a `break`. As you noticed, it would not work if you replaced `break` with `return`.

---

The rationale is explained towards the end of the section. In substance, `if` has a special treatment to allow constructs such as:

```
if(DEBUG) { ... }
```

where DEBUG may be a compile time constant.

Comment: In that description, there is a line which says that the error will be produced if:
`A break, continue, return, or throw statement cannot complete normally. `. Well, its fine with **continue** and **return**. But not **break**. :/

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh that is unrelated.

Comment: Nice analysis on the "completes normally" part.

Comment: @black "iff" is a common abbreviation in mathematics for "if and only if".

Comment: @chepner I wouldn't expect it in a formal context though, whether it's ISO (as for C++) or not.

Comment: The "unreachable code" problem is uncomputable in the general case, as it's a transformation on the general case. What can be done, however, are solutions based on certain classes of unreachable code, for which many assumptions are made, as you can see below.

Comment: @black Why not? It's [an English word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iff)...

Answer (score 11):

As explained in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20299947/1189885), the specific construct `if(compile-time-false)` is exempt from the unreachability rules as an explicit backdoor. In this case, the compiler treats your `break` as reachable because of that.

Answer (score 7):

From [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)

> An if-then statement can complete normally if at least one of the
>   following is true:
>
> **> The if-then statement is reachable and the condition expression is not
>   a constant expression whose value is true.**
>
> **> The then-statement can complete normally.**

So `if(false)` is allowed.

> This ability to "conditionally compile" has a significant impact on,
>   and relationship to, binary compatibility. If a set of classes
>   that use such a "flag" variable are compiled and conditional code is
>   omitted, it does not suffice later to distribute just a new version of
>   the class or interface that contains the definition of the flag. A
>   change to the value of a flag is, therefore, not binary compatible
>   with pre-existing binaries . (There are other reasons for
>   such incompatibility as well, such as the use of constants in case
>   labels in switch statements;)

Answer (score 4):

Basically, *unreachable code* is detected by analyzing the program *statically* ***without*** actually running the code. While the condition will be checked at *runtime*. So, when this analysis takes place it does not actually look in to the condition but just check that `break;` is accessible(*reachable*) via `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The core reason Java doesn't detect **all** unreachable statements is that it's generally impossible to answer whether the code is reachable or not. This follows from the fact that [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is undecidable over Turing machines.

So, it's clear that all unreachable statements cannot be detected, but why not to try evaluating conditions? Imagine now that the condition used is not just `false` but something like `~x == x`. For example, all these statements will print `true` for every `int x` ([source](http://habrahabr.ru/post/202162/)).

```
    System.out.println((x + x & 1) == 0);
    System.out.println((x + -x & 1) == 0);
    System.out.println((-x & 1) == (x & 1));
    System.out.println(((-x ^ x) & 1) == 0);
    System.out.println((x * 0x80 & 0x56) == 0);
    System.out.println((x << 1 ^ 0x1765) != 0);
```

The statements can be rather complicated; it takes time to resolve them. It would significantly increase build time, and after all, it will not detect all unreachable statements. Compiler was designed to take some efforts but not spend too much time for that.

The only question remained is: where to stop resolving conditions? The reasons for that don't seem to have mathematical justification and are based on usage scenario. Rationale for your particular case is given by [JLS-14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)