# Syntax with missed Expression for basic for-loop

Tags: java, c, for-loop

Some days ago I was talking with my colleagues about this code in Java:

```
for( ; ; ) { }
```

Nothing special here, just an infinite loop.

But we wonder why this is syntactically correct. If you take a look to [JLS §14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) you'll see this:

```
for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

I understand that `ForInit` and `ForUpdate` can be omitted. But at least I would expect that `Expression` is mandatory, like in while-loop:

```
while() {} // compile error, Expression is missed
```

So why can Expression be omitted on a for-loop? And even one think more - why is missed Expression resolved to `true`? My expectation would be that empty Expression is resolved to `false`.

The same think is valid for other languages (I've try it with C and JavaScript, but I believe every language with for-loops behaves in that way).

Why is an Expression clause not mandatory in for-loop (but in while-loop)? Why does empty Expression resolve to `true` and not to `false`?

Comment: You have too much time on your hands if you're worried about this :)

Comment: Interstingly,  both `for(;;)` and `while(true)` ae replaced with only one `goto 0` instruction :P

Comment: @tokamak made my day :D

Comment: @TheLostMind yes I saw it. I took a look into bytecode with javap :)

Comment: @WaleryStrauch - Yes. Same here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299914/iffalse-vs-whilefalse-unreachable-code-vs-dead-code

Comment: @JasonZ this is completely different question

Comment: @WaleryStrauch It's the same question to me, you are asking why expression can be omitted in the for loop, that question was asking the same thing.

Comment: @JasonZ:  Those two questions are *worlds* apart.  This is asking about the lexical structure, *not* why one statement compiles with a specific expression and another doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The rationale starts [in JLS 14.14.1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.1) and continues into 14.14.1.2, emphasis mine.

> If the `ForInit` part **is not present**, no action is taken.
>
> If the `Expression` **is not present**, or it is present and the value resulting from its evaluation (including any possible unboxing) is true, then the contained `Statement` is executed...

The JLS permits the blank `ForInit`, `Expression` and `ForUpdate` statements and has conditions to deal with their absence, so omitting them is acceptable.

It is ***not*** permissible to do so with `while` loops, [per JLS 14.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12).

> The `Expression` must have type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs.

From this, the specification is *not* permitting a blank expression to be passed through, since that would result in a compile-time error per above.

---

If you're looking for a slightly more historical reason, the [C specification mandates this as well](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

[image]

Since Java took heavy inspiration from C (and is mostly implemented in it), it makes perfect sense for Java's loops to behave similarly to C's loops, and this is how they behave:  expressions are optional in C's `for`  statement, and mandatory in its `while` statement.

Comment: Yes... I saw JLS already also. But my question was 'why' is it so?

Comment: "Because Oracle said so" is about the best thing you can go on from here.  It's also consistent with C, which Java is mostly based off of.

Comment: I wrote this question because I hope someone has better answer than "Because Oracle said so". Sure, I believe java makes it to be consistent with C.
But what are the initial reason for this decision? Maybe there are historical reasons like 'it was easier to implement compiler in that way' or 'just mistake - but for compatibility reason it wasn't change afterwards'.
Maybe there are other reason... My question aims to find this out.

Comment: @WaleryStrauch:  I've added another resource, but the ultimate answer is *still* "because Oracle/Sun said so".  There's strong evidence to suggest it took inspiration from C, which makes sense, but that decision was still made by the original language framers.