# Why is an if/else if/else for a simple boolean not giving an "unreachable code" error

Tags: java, boolean, unreachable-code

Why is this code not giving an "unreachable code" error? Since a boolean can only be true or false.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean a = false;
    if (a == true) {

    } else if (a == false) {

    } else {
        int c = 0;
        c = c + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: See the second half of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276378/unreachable-code-compiler-error

Comment: Also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299914/iffalse-vs-whilefalse-unreachable-code-vs-dead-code

Comment: A check in the JLS gives the answer (as always): *"The else-statement is reachable iff the if-then-else statement is reachable. "*. Since both `if` and `else if` are reachable, the `else` statement is it as well.

Comment: Refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21

Comment: @Tom This should be the answer :)

Comment: can't boolean values be set to `null`?

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin no, you confuse with `Boolean` which is object. `boolean` is primitive.

Comment: There are loads of examples of code that is not unreachable but can never be reached - e.g. `default` cases in switches where all possibilities already covered. Why should `boolean` be special just because there are only 2 values?

Comment: it is possible in multithreaded environment that first it is false when it just reaches else if variable is again true

Comment: `if (a == true)`, `if (a == false)` <-- Don't ever do this when `a` is a `boolean`. Just do `if (a)` and `if (!a)`.

Comment: @jpmc26 I am 99% sure both generate the same bytecode. Use what is more readable in the context you need it in.

Comment: @AlexR It is a matter of style and presentation. Seeing the code, `a == true` without there being a *very* good reason why screams that the author lacks understanding about what `==` does. I admit that there are rare cases where it might make sense, but these are *extremely* rare. (They might be a bit more common in weakly or dynamically typed languages, but this is Java.) Certainly, in this example, it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not opposed to your general statement, just to the "ever" part of it ;-)

Comment: @AlexR To be fair, my comment includes the `if` and the parentheses and that `a ` is a `boolean` (primitive). It *never* makes sense in the full context (a single boolean check on a non-nullable type).

Comment: This might help: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From [JLS 14.21. Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.

and

> The else-statement is reachable iff the if-then-else statement is reachable.

Your if-then-else statement is reachable. So, by the definition the compiler thinks that the else-statement is reachable.

Note: Interestingly the following code also compiles

```
// This is ok
if (false) { /* do something */ }
```

This is not true for `while`

```
// This will not compile
while (false) { /* do something */ }
```

because the reachability definition for `while` is different (emphasis mine):

> The contained statement is reachable iff the while statement is reachable **and the condition expression is not a constant expression whose value is false**.

Comment: I don't know if this is what the Java designers had in mind, but it can be useful to have `if (COMPILE TIME CONSTANT EXPRESSION) { ... }` constructs where the COMPILE TIME CONSTANT EXPRESSION might be either true or false depending on the environment.

Comment: @zwol that's exactly the reason why such behavior exists. I also think to remember that in the very first version of JVM `if(false)` was not compilable because clearly unreachable. Also note that this behavior comes in handy to put `if(true){return;}` in the middle of a method while developing for debug purpose. Compiler perfectly knows that everything that comes after is unreachable, but it still allows you to write it since it's just useful to have it.